# Node + xmldom - Replace exisiting blank xml field with value

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, domparser

I am using XMLDOM node module for replacing xml field value. The below code works well, if i am replacing xml field which already has value with some new value. But the code gets error out, if the xml field is blank and I replacing/setting it to some value.

The code works for:

```
<accountId>12345</accountId>
//Replace to 
<accountId>99999</accountId>
```

The code fails when:

```
<accountId></accountId>
//Replace to
<accountId>99999</accountId>
```

Error message: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Javascript code with xmldom modle:

```
    await (function replaceRequestData(callback)    {
//requestPath is the path from where xml structure is read
        fs.readFile(requestPath, 'utf8', function(err,data)    {
            var tempXML = new dom().parseFromString(data);
            tempXML.getElementsByTagName("accountId")[0].childNodes[0].data = 99999;
            console.log(tempXML.getElementsByTagName("accountId")[0].childNodes[0].data);
            var xmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(tempXML);
            callback(null, xmlString);
            fs.writeFile(requestPath, xmlString, 'utf8');
            //console.log(requestPath);
        });

    });
```

Comment: So what does the `console.log()` line tells before & after replacing the value for the empty value case?

Comment: @Raptor error message is - Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: which line does the error occur?  by the way, `console.log()` should output something, instead of an error message.